# Is there a native Javascript way to achieve helper: "clone" behavior from jQuery draggable?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

In jQuery, I can clone an element to prevent the original from being removed when dragging and dropping:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
  helper: "clone"
});
```

Is there a way to do this with native Javascript?

I'm currently using this code for the `drop` listener:

```
el.addEventListener(
  'drop',
  function(e) {
      // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
      if (e.stopPropagation){
        e.stopPropagation();
      }

      this.classList.remove('over');

      var binId = this.id;
      var item = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
      this.appendChild(item);
      // call the passed drop function
      scope.$apply(function(scope) {
          var fn = scope.drop();
          if ('undefined' !== typeof fn) {
            fn(item.id, binId);
          }
      });
      return false;
  },
  false
```

);

Comment: If you want to clone the dragged/dropped element, you can call the [*cloneNode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method on the dropped element. To clone all the content too, pass *true* as the only parameter (the default is false, which doesn't clone the content). Note that cloning drops all listeners from cloned nodes other than those added in–line (i.e. as attributes).

Comment: @RobG thanks this worked for me. Would accept as answer